# Decoupling a system of four linear $1$-st order ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, quantum-computing

I have a system of four $1$-st order ODEs. $$ \dot{p_1} = -2\beta^2 q_1 - \gamma p_1 + \Delta p_2 $$ $$ \dot{p_2} = -2\beta^2 q_2 - \gamma p_2 + \Delta p_1 $$ $$ \dot{q_1} = 2\alpha^2 p_1 + \gamma q_1 + \Delta q_2 $$ $$ \dot{q_2} = 2\alpha^2 p_2 + \gamma q_2 - \Delta q_1 $$
here $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$  and $\Delta$ are all non-zero constants.

How can I decouple this set of equations?

I have seen few examples for two $1$-st order ODEs but I am unable to do for this one. Any Suggestions?

I know the decoupled ones will be equations of **order-4**. But how can I get those using *Mathematica*?

Comment: Quick clarification:  in the last equation, is q2 to be specified twice? (I'm wondering if there should be a q1)

Comment: Ahhhh no.... sorry... corrected now.

Comment: Hah!  Thanks.  It didn't pass the "sniff test". FWIW I was looking for special structure that would permit a symbolic Jordan Decomposition.

Comment: Thanks!!.... Maybe if you have time.,... you can take a look.... I will be really happy to learn some hidden things.... and sorry again... I should have noticed the error.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I thought "decouple" would mean an answer in the form of four first-order equations, each in terms of its own variable. That is not what you want, though?

Comment: @MichaelE2  Could you give a non-trivial example (all coefficients are non zero) where there are first order "decoupled" ODE's?  I thought I understood the meaning of decoupling in the context of systems of ODEs,  but perhaps you can give me a chance of broadening my horizons.

Comment: @Artes I've added an answer. Let me know if you know the method by another name. I have to say that that my understanding was learned "on the job" and not from written works, although I've seen my version done and called decoupling before. It could be called "factoring into a direct product of 1-dim. systems," I suppose; or possibly "diagonalization."  Maybe I learned the wrong term from someone who misused it.

Comment: The diagonalization-decoupling method is like finding normal modes from the linearization of an oscillatory system.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you your answer (+1) even though I find your terminology misused. I guess it comes from combining quite different issues which nevertheless   are sometimes associated as you mentioned "normal modes from the linearization of oscillatory systems".  Since our linear system is diagonizable I guess your procedure should be called constructing eigensystems or as you mention diagonalization.  I'm not sure whether my approach is usually  called decoupling, nonetheless it is used in the context of nonlinear systems where sometimes it appears the only chance to go ahead.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The concept of decoupling is usually used among physicists and I talked to mathematicians who did not know what it meant, though they had not anything to do with nonlinear differential equations.  while theoretical physicists play with them everyday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\Delta$ I am using for simplicity $a,b,c,d$ respectively. Now I rewrite given system of equations in the form $Lhs-Rhs=0$, i.e we define.

```
deq = { p1'[t] + 2 b^2 q1[t] + c p1[t] - d p2[t], 
       p2'[t] + 2 b ^2 q2[t] + c p2[t] - d p1[t], 
       q1'[t] - 2 a^2 p1[t] - c q1[t] - d q2[t], 
       q2'[t] - 2 a^2 p2[t] - c q2[t] + d q1[t]};
```

and the original system is trivially equivalent to `deq = {0,0,0,0}`. Taking a closer look at the original system, we conclude that in order to get a decoupled equation for $p''''_1$ we need using the third, the second and the first derivatives of the variables as well as the fourth derivative of $p''''_1$. Then we can use `Eliminate` to get rid of all variables except for $p''''_1,p'''_1,p''_1,p'_1$ and $p_1$:

```
eq =
Collect[
  Eliminate[
    Join[ deq, D[deq, {t, 2}], D[deq, t], {D[deq[[1]], {t, 3}]}] 
    == ConstantArray[0, 13], 
    { p2'''[t], p2''[t], p2'[t], p2[t], q1'''[t], q1''[t], q1'[t], q1[t], 
      q2'''[t], q2''[t], q2'[t], q2[t]}], 
 {p1''''[t], p1'''[t], p''[t], p1[t], p1[t]}, Simplify]
```

> ```
> p1''''[t] == (-16 a^4 b^4 + 8 a^2 b^2 c^2 - c^4 + d^4) p1[t]  
>               -4 c d^2 p1'[t] + 2 (-4 a^2 b^2 + c^2) p1''[t]
> ```

We have used `Collect[ eq, vars, Simplify]` for appropriate simplification of coefficients in this linear differential equation.  `ConstantArray[0, 13]` stands for `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` since we have to use equations in `Eliminate`. We can rewrite it also in TeX format `TeXForm[eq /. p1 -> Subscript[p, 1]]` and slightly improving its form we have
$${p_1}^{(4)}(t)=2 \left(c^2-4 a^2 b^2\right) p_1''(t) -4 c d^2 p_1'(t)+\left(d^4-(c^2-4 a^2 b^2)^2\right)p_1(t)$$
and this is our differential equation for $p_1$. Analogously we can find equations for other variables $p_2,q_1,q_2$.

Comment: Can you please explain what does ```ConstantArray``` does? why there is 0 and 13?

Comment: Mentioned about it in the answer.  It stands for `{ 0, ... 0}` .

Comment: Please note that the problem statement changed after this answer was written.  I think the solution is still in the same spirit.

Comment: @EricBrown  Note that I've edited the answer after changing the equations.  Why don't you read the answer carefully, do you?

Comment: @Artes "Why don't you read the answer carefully, do you?"  Seems you changed the answer two hours after I discovered a problem in the question and made that comment. In fact, I read the question so carefully that I found the mistake in spite of not knowing the original context. (vide supra) My note was a courtesy to you and to others interested in this topic. I don't understand why it garnered such a visceral response.

Comment: It's fine... @Artes solution works well in evry case (I have checked for few). So it's fine....

Comment: @EricBrown  Regardless of any comments the method was appropriate though for slightly different equation. Right after Your comment under the question I changed the equation in my answer as suggested  by  editing the original poster, tough haven't rewritten the deq system.  So your comment under my answer wasn't really up-to-date and suggestion "the solution is still in the same spirit" wasn'r right.  Nevertheless I had to correct one sign in `deq` system,  though the rest  of the answer had been correctly updated earlier.  Right?

Comment: @Artes "The solution is still in the same spirit" I intended this to mean that the proposed algorithm seemed correct in spite of the specific details of the problem formulation, rather than the algorithm is wrong in the same way that the posed problem is wrong.  I regret that my lack of precision has caused an issue.

Answer (score 6):

@Artes asked about my interpretation of "decoupled." Since the OP has accepted Artes's interpretation, I assume this approach does not answer the OP's question. However, if others have my interpretation and are searching for a solution in Mathematica for this form of "decoupling," this answer may serve a useful purpose as a second answer.

If we have a system $p'(t) = A\mathbin{.}p(t)$, and $P^{-1}AP=D$ is diagonal, then the system may be written in the form
$$r'(t) = D\mathbin{.}r(t) \,,$$
that is,
$$r_i'(t) = \lambda_i r_i(t) \,,\quad i=1,2,3,4\,,$$
where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.
The new variables $r$ are related to the old variables $p$ by
$$p = P\mathbin{.}r \;.$$
The new system is said to be "decoupled." In this sense, not every linear system can be decoupled. Instead, a system can be factored into a product of independent systems, according to the Jordan decomposition of $A$.

It is relatively straight-forward to implement the foregoing using `JordanDecomposition[]`.
In the OP's case, we have symbolic parameters, and the `JordanDecomposition[]` will return a result that is generically valid. One would be advised to check its validity on any particular set of values for the parameters. I've left off pretty much all checks (that the system is linear and homogeneous, that the matrix is diagonalizable), because it was easy to inspect the results by eye as I went along.

```
origODE = {
   p1'[t] + 2 b^2 q1[t] + c p1[t] - d p2[t],
   p2'[t] + 2 b^2 q2[t] + c p2[t] - d p1[t],
   q1'[t] - 2 a^2 p1[t] - c q1[t] - d q2[t],
   q2'[t] - 2 a^2 p2[t] - c q2[t] + d q2[t]};

dvars = {p1, p2, q1, q2};
dvarst = Through[dvars[t]];

{trans, diag} = JordanDecomposition@  (* = {P, D} *)
   Last@CoefficientArrays[
     First@SolveValues[origODE == 0, D[dvarst, t]], dvarst];

newvars = {r1, r2, r3, r4};
newvarst = Through[newvars[t]];
dvarst == trans.newvarst // Thread;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the decoupled ODE:

```
decoupledODE = Thread[D[newvarst, t] == diag . newvarst]
```

> ```
> (*
> {r1'[t] == (-Sqrt[-4 a^2 b^2 + c^2] - d)              r1[t],
>  r2'[t] == (Sqrt[-4 a^2 b^2 + c^2] - d)               r2[t],
>  r3'[t] == 1/2 (d - Sqrt[-16 a^2 b^2 + (-2 c + d)^2]) r3[t],
>  r4'[t] == 1/2 (d + Sqrt[-16 a^2 b^2 + (-2 c + d)^2]) r4[t]}
> *)
> ```

Checking the solutions of the original and decoupled ODEs.
The solutions are very large and `Simplify` takes forever, so I settled on numerical verification. To do this, I picked an *ad hoc* initial condition and solved the two equivalent IVPs.

```
decoupledICS = newvarst == Range@4 /. t -> 0;
decoupledIVP = DSolveValue[{decoupledODE, decoupledICS}, newvarst, t];

origICS = dvarst == trans . Range@4 /. t -> 0;
origIVP = DSolveValue[ (* takes ~4.2 sec *)
   {Thread[origODE == 0], origICS},
   dvarst, t];
ByteCount[origIVP]
```

> ```
> (*  3239856  *)
> ```

We compare the solutions for particular values of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` at a particular time `t`:

```
dvarst == trans . newvarst // Thread // 
  ReplaceAll@
   Join[Thread[dvarst -> origIVP], Thread[newvarst -> decoupledIVP]] //
  ReplaceAll@{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 7, d -> 3, t -> -5.`40}
```

> ```
> (*  {True, True, True, True}  *)
> ```

Repeat 100 random times. If you don't use arbitrary precision, then you should use a standard floating-point test for approximately equal or approximately zero, since there will be round-off error.

```
Table[ (* takes ~3.3 sec *)
  origIVP - trans . decoupledIVP /. 
   Thread[{a, b, c, d, t} -> 
     RandomReal[10 {-1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 40]],
  100] // MatrixQ[#, PossibleZeroQ] &
```

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```